# Проблема с руссификацией Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, datatable

я использую datatable  для отображения таблицы но при русификации отваливается код js который отвечает за скрытие столбцов , это происходит только при вставке

```
language: {
url: '/js/Russian.json'}
```

при этом ,если вставить весь скрипт в js файл (mytable) не работает русификация , как и Bootstrap стили

в файле json находятся данные для русификации

```
{
"processing": "Подождите...",
"search": "Поиск:",
"lengthMenu": "Показать _MENU_ записей",
"info": "Записи с _START_ до _END_ из _TOTAL_ записей",
"infoEmpty": "Записи с 0 до 0 из 0 записей",
"infoFiltered": "(отфильтровано из _MAX_ записей)",
"loadingRecords": "Загрузка записей...",
"zeroRecords": "Записи отсутствуют.",
"emptyTable": "В таблице отсутствуют данные",
"paginate": {
    "first": "Первая",
    "previous": "Предыдущая",
    "next": "Следующая",
    "last": "Последняя"
},
"aria": {
    "sortAscending": ": активировать для сортировки столбца по возрастанию",
    "sortDescending": ": активировать для сортировки столбца по убыванию"
},
```

а здесь уже сам код

```js
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    "scrollY": "400px",
    "scrollX": true, // добавить опцию scrollX
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "fixedHeader": true,
    

});
// Создаем новый элемент div с id="table-controls" и вставляем его перед элементом #mytable_wrapper
var tableControls = $('<div id="table-controls"></div>').insertBefore('#mytable_wrapper');

// Создаем кнопку "Hide All" и добавляем ее в элемент #table-controls
var toggleAllButton = $('<button class=" btn-sm btn btn-outline-dark" id="toggle-all-button">ВЫКЛ ВСЁ</button>');
toggleAllButton.appendTo(tableControls);

// Для каждого столбца в таблице создаем кнопку "Hide" и добавляем ее в элемент #table-controls
table.columns().every(function() {
var columnIndex = this.index();
var columnName = this.header().textContent.trim();
var button = $('<button class="toggle-button btn-sm btn btn-outline-dark" data-column="' + columnIndex + '">ВЫКЛ ' + columnName + '</button>');
button.appendTo(tableControls);
});

// Добавляем обработчик клика на кнопки "Hide" в элементе #table-controls
$('.toggle-button').click(function() {
// Получаем индекс столбца, связанный с кнопкой "Hide", и получаем ссылку на этот столбец в DataTable
var columnIndex = $(this).data('column');
var column = table.column(columnIndex);

// Инвертируем текущее значение видимости столбца и изменяем текст на кнопке соответственно
column.visible(!column.visible());
$(this).text(column.visible() ? 'ВЫКЛ ' + column.header().textContent.trim() : 'ВКЛ ' + column.header().textContent.trim());

// Изменяем текст на кнопке "Hide All" в зависимости от видимости столбцов и перерисовываем таблицу
toggleAllButton.text(table.columns(':visible').length ? 'ВКЛ ВСЕ' : 'ВЫКЛ ВСЕ');
table.draw();
});

// Добавляем обработчик клика на кнопку "Hide All" в элементе #table-controls
toggleAllButton.click(function() {
// Получаем массив видимости всех столбцов DataTable и инвертируем его значения
var visible = table.columns().visible();
visible = visible.map(function(e) { 
e.data = !e.data; 
return e;
});
table.columns().visible(visible);
let visible_check = table.columns().visible();
/*let visSwitch=
table.columns().every(function(visSwitch) {

} */ 
// Создаем переменную allVisible и устанавливаем ее значение по умолчанию в true
let allVisible = true;

// Проходим циклом по массиву visible
for (let i = 0; i < visible.length; i++) {
// Если хотя бы одно значение в массиве равно false, устанавливаем allVisible в false и выходим из цикла
if (!visible[i]) {
allVisible = false;
break;
}
}

// Определяем текст для кнопки в зависимости от того, скрыты ли все столбцы или нет
let buttonText = allVisible ? 'ВКЛ ВСЕ' : 'ВЫКЛ ВСЕ';

// Устанавливаем текст на кнопке
$(this).text(buttonText);

// Для каждой кнопки переключения столбца находим соответствующий столбец в таблице и устанавливаем текст на кнопке в зависимости от того, скрыт ли столбец или нет

$('.toggle-button').each(function() {
var columnIndex = $(this).data('column');
var column = table.column(columnIndex);
$(this).text(allVisible ? 'ВКЛ ' + column.header().textContent.trim() : 'ВЫКЛ ' + column.header().textContent.trim());
});
// Если все столбцы видимы, скрываем их, иначе показываем
if (allVisible) {
table.columns().visible(false);
} else {
table.columns().visible(true);
}
table.columns.adjust().draw();
});

// Данный код добавляет обработчик клика на кнопку "Hide All" в элементе с id "table-controls". При клике на кнопку, видимость всех столбцов в таблице DataTable инвертируется, то есть, если какие-то столбцы были видимы, то они становятся невидимыми, и наоборот.
// Далее, текст кнопки "Hide All" или "Show All" изменяется в зависимости от текущего состояния видимости столбцов. Кроме того, для каждой кнопки, которая отвечает за отдельный столбец, текст также изменяется в зависимости от его текущей видимости.
// Наконец, вызывается метод "columns.adjust().draw()", который перерисовывает таблицу после изменения видимости столбцов.
// В целом, данный код отвечает за скрытие/отображение столбцов таблицы DataTable и изменение текста на кнопках, которые управляют видимостью отдельных столбцов.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.12.2/i18n/Russian.json"> -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- bootstrap js -->
       
    
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-5h4UG+6GOuV9qXh6HqOLwZMY4mnLPraeTrjT5v07o347pj6IkfuoASuGBhfDsp3d" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane Smith</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bob Johnson</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>Japan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alice Brown</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Sydney</td>
      <td>Australia</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    <script src="./js/mytable.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема заключается в том, что после загрузки JSON-файла, структура HTML-документа изменяется, и элементы, на которые привязаны обработчики событий, перестают существовать.

Необходимо выполнить этот код после того, как будет выполнена загрузка JSON-файла. Например, вы можете использовать событие load на объекте window или метод $.getJSON в jQuery с обратным вызовом:

```
    $.getJSON('/js/lang/Russian.json', function() {
  // Обработчики кликов на кнопки должны быть здесь, после загрузки JSON-файла
  // ...
  $('.toggle-button').click(function() {
    // код для скрытия/отображения столбцов
    // ...
  });

  $('#toggle-all-button').click(function() {
    // код для скрытия/отображения всех столбцов
    
  });
});
```